# Finding structures from web articles with Python

Tags: python

I'm looking for some Python tool, that can help me determine content structures from an article website such as http://www.bbc.co.uk/. I used boilerplate removal library - Boilerpipe to clean the web page from unwanted stuff (banners, links, pictures, etc). 
Now when I have only relevant content, I want to automatically determine what string is title, author, date, date of article updating, what is the article itself. Problem is, I am not only going to use it for transparent article pages, that has most of those information in HTML tags such as `<title>Title</title>`. I'd like to be able to determine it from tags like `<div>28.11.2011<p>John Cusack on Syria conflict</div>`.
Is there any tool that can help me with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isn't scrapy meant for that kind of stuff? http://scrapy.org/

Comment: Scrapy is probably the tool I'm looking for, but it is not very easy to learn or to make it do what I want. Any hints on how to determine title, author, etc. using scrapy?

Answer (score 0):

You can get content from articles easy with the follow "tools":

1. scrapy (recommended, but have greater learning curve)
2. newspaper (gives you immediately title, author, text, images, videos, etc. )
3. goose-extractor (is like newspaper)